# Density of probability in a square

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have a square
$$\{(x,y) : x \in [0,1], y \in [0,1] \}.$$
We suppose that we have $X$ and $Y$ are the coordinates in this square that are uniformly distributed.
Why does the joint density is $f(x,y) = 1/xy$?
How do I evaluate $$P(Y \ge x | Y \ge 1/2) ?$$
Thank you very much...
Cordially,

Leonardo

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, and independent, then their joint density is just $f(x,y)=1$.... not $f(x,y)=1/(xy)$.

Comment: Hint: Draw the portions of the square covered by $Y\geq X$ and $Y\geq 1/2$.

Comment: $1/(xy)$ isn't a probability distribution on the square.  (It doesn't even define a finite measure)

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. What I want to know is why does the density is 1 under the area of the region?

Comment: You should change your question to match what you say in your comment, especially since you have no answers yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) $(x,y)$ is uniform so it's density is constant, say $c$. To determine $c$, note that $F(1,1)=1$ or

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1c\,dxdy=1\quad\Rightarrow\quad c=1.
$$

(2) It's not clear what do you mean by $\mathsf{P}(Y\ge x\mid Y\ge 1/2)$. If $x$ is a constant, then

$$
\mathsf{P}(Y\ge x\mid Y\ge 1/2)=2(1-x)\wedge 1
$$

because the marginal distribution of $Y$ is uniform over $[0,1]$.

If you actually mean $\mathsf{P}(Y\ge X\mid Y\ge 1/2)$, then

$$
\mathsf{P}(Y\ge X\mid Y\ge 1/2)=\frac{\mathsf{P}(Y\ge X,Y\ge 1/2)}{\mathsf{P}(Y\ge 1/2)}=2\int_{0}^1\int_{x\vee 1/2}^1\,dydx=\frac{3}{4},
$$

which is the relative area of the part of rectangle $[0,1]\times[1/2,1]$ where $y\ge x$.

Comment: thanks a lot!
You helped so much.
Cordially